# Excel compare two columns

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I have two columns in excel

A and B

I want to compare both and highlight where there is a match, however it is not a direct comparison

Column A has data like this

ABC123

whereas Column B only has

123

So I want to find 123 in Column A from Column B and highlight the match.

I need to do this for 9000 records

Pleas help

Comment: Could you give some more concrete examples of inputs and expected matches? For example, will A ever contain `ABCD12`, and if it does, should it match `12` or `D12`?

Comment: it should match just 12, so it only need to match exactly what is displayed in Column B. For example if Column B has 123 and Column A has ABC123 then only 123 should match

Answer (score 3):

You can do this without additiona formula's and VBA as well. Make a conditional format on cell B1 that is a formula:

```
=NOT(ISERROR(SEARCH(B1,A1)))
```

Note: Make sure that the values are B1 and A1, NOT $B$1 and $A$1.

Under Applies to fill in "B:B". Add a nice format for matched values.

Answer (score 2):

`=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(B1,A1)),"Match","")`

This in column C will work for you.

What this does is use `Search(find text,in text,[position])` to see whether the exact string appears in column A. If it does it will return a number (the position that this string starts in) so `=IF(ISNUMBER(` can use that data accordingly.

[image]

Comment: How do I make the match change to red color and how do i extend the formula for 9000 records?

Comment: Easiest way is to put the formula in cell C1 then double click the black square in the bottom right of the cell, it will auto fill to the end of the data in the column next to it as long as there aren't any blanks. Conditional formatting for if column c equals "Match" to go red...

Comment: @HC17758091 How'd it go? Any issues?

Answer (score 1):

An option is to strip out the letters from column A and try a direct match

You can use a UDF for this

```
Public Function StripChar(strInput As String) As String
    Dim i As Long: For i = 1 To Len(strInput)
        If IsNumeric(Mid(strInput, i, 1)) Then StripChar = StripChar + CStr(Mid(strInput, i, 1))
    Next i
End Function
```

Then you can either use a helper function or direct conditional formatting with the following formula:

> =IF(StripChar(A2)=TEXT(B2,"0"),TRUE,FALSE)